# How to test a C++ library usability in configure.in?

Tags: c++, autotools, configure, usability, autoconf

I'm working on a C++ project on GNU/Linux and I'm looking for a way to test the existence and usability of IBM Informix's library with the Autotools - namely, editing a `configure.in`. I don't have experience with Autotools, so basically I'm picking up from the project's `configure.in` *et al.* scripts and copying&changing where I feel needs to be changed. IOW, I've been adapting from the existing text in `configure.in`.

So far I've been using successfully the `AC_CHECK_LIB` in `configure.in` to test whether a certain library both exists and is usable. But this only seems to work with libraries with *functions*, not e.g. classes. Namely, this fails when testing Informix's `libifc++.so` library:

```
AC_CHECK_LIB(ifc++, ITString, 
        INFORMIX_LIB="-L$INFORMIX_LIB_LOCATION/c++ -lifc++ -L$INFORMIX_LIB_LOCATION -L$INFORMIX_LIB_LOCATION/dmi -L$INFORMIX_LIB_LOCATION/esql -lifdmi -lifsql -lifasf -lifgen -lifos -lifgls -lifglx $INFORMIX_LIB_LOCATION/esql/checkapi.o -lm -ldl -lcrypt -lnsl",
        echo "* WARNING: libifc++.so not found!"
        INFORMIX_INC=""
        INFORMIX_LIB=""
)
```

I've also tried using other combinations, like `ITString::ITString`, etc.

I haven't found a "pure" function in Informix's API (i.e., one that isn't contexted in a C++ class). So I'm hoping that either there's a way to use `AC_CHECK_LIB` in this context, or there's another `autoconf`/`configure.in` "command" for this specific use.

Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There might be a cleaner way of achieving this, but I think your problem is that C++ methods get "mangled" to allow additional information about the method (argument & return types etc) to be encoded. For example; the method `int A::foo(void)` will get mangled to something like `__ZN1A3fooEv`.

So you need to find the mangled name of a method in the library. You can do this by using the [`nm` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nm_(Unix)) on Unix-like OSs:

```
$ nm libifc++.so | grep ITString
```

It's worth mentioning that the exact mangling format varies across different compilers; and so by embedding a certain compiler's mangled symbol in your `configure.in` it may not work on other platforms - YMMV.

Note: you can use the [`c++filt`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/c_002b_002bfilt.html) utility to demangle a name back to it's human-readable form; so for the example I gave previously:

```
$ c++filt __ZN1A3fooEv
A::foo()
```

See [Name Mangling in C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B) on Wikipedia for more information.

Comment: Works-For-Me.

I had thought about doing something like this, but it seemed like a hack. For example, I'm not sure what happens if the code is recompiled with a different Informix library version (I expect the mangled name to change).

But hey, it works! :-)

Comment: This should continue to work with a new library version (assuming the class and method names do not change), but may break if your compiler version changes, and will almost certainly break if someone else tries to compile your code on another compiler or compiler version.

Comment: Too verbose, seriously, look up my answer on the bottom.

Answer (score 17):

You've discovered a shortcoming of autotools, but one that can't really be helped. Autotools checks for symbol names in the library binary, and unlike C where symbol names of functions are identical to the function names, C++ "mangles" function's symbol names to accomplish things like function overloading. What's worse is that C++ doesn't really even have a "standard" mangling convention, so different C++ compilers may produce different symbol names for the same function. Thus, autotools can't check for C++ symbol names in a reliable manner.

Does the library you are trying to use have any functions that are declared with `extern "C"`? This causes the C++ compiler to generate standardized C-style symbol names, and autotools will be able to find them.

I ran into this issue trying to detect [gtest](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) and [gmock](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/) (the Google unit testing and object mocking frameworks) with Autotools, and here's what I came up with:

```
# gtest has a main function in the gtest_main library with C linkage, we can test for that.
AC_CHECK_LIB([gtest_main], [main], [HAVE_GTEST=1] [TEST_LIBS="$TEST_LIBS -lgtest_main"], 
      AC_MSG_WARN([libgtest (Google C++ Unit Testing Framework) is not installed. Will not be able to make check.])) 

# gmock has no functions with C linkage, so this is a roundabout way of testing for it. We create a small test
# program that tries to instantiate one of gmock's objects, and try to link it with -lgmock and see if it works.
if test "$HAVE_GTEST"                                                                 
then                                                                                  
  saved_ldflags="${LDFLAGS}"                                                          
  LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} -lgtest -lgmock"                                                
  AC_LINK_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM([#include <gmock/gmock.h>], [testing::Cardinality dummy])],
    [TEST_LIBS="$TEST_LIBS -lgmock"] [HAVE_GMOCK=1],                                           
    [AC_MSG_WARN([libgmock (Google C++ Object Mocking Framework) is not installed. Will not be able to make check.])])
  LDFLAGS="${saved_ldflags}"                                                                                          
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

If the library you are checking for supports [pkg-config](http://pkg-config.freedesktop.org/wiki/), this becomes very easy. Here is all I added to my `configure.in` to check for and enable `gtest` and `gmock`:

```
dnl ************************************
dnl Check for googletest and googlemock
dnl ************************************

PKG_CHECK_MODULES(gtestmock, libgtest >= 0.4.0, libgmock >= 0.4.0)
AC_SUBST(gtestmock_LIBS)
AC_SUBST(gtestmock_CFLAGS)
```

And then in my `Makefile.am` somewhere:

```
sometarget_CXXFLAGS = $(gtestmock_CFLAGS) $(AM_CXXFLAGS)
sometarget_LDADD    = $(gtestmock_LIBS)
```

Pretty trivial, eh?

Comment: [There are problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220946/pkg-check-modules-considered-harmful/10229811#10229811) with using pkg-config, though.  And, more fundamentally, pkg-config and the autotools work in a different way.  Autoconf checks for features, whereas pkg-config tests for package versions.  If you're trying to do things the autotools way, which should give you maximum compatibility across systems, I wouldn't suggest using pkg-config at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
AC_LANG_CPLUSPLUS
AC_CHECK_LIB(Sockets, main)
```

Caveat: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/autoconf/2006-09/msg00019.html

Comment: A bit more explanation would help. Your sample requires that exactly `main` is specified and only checks for existance of the library. But the generated program has UB because in C++ `main` is not allowed to call `main`. Which BTW is mentioned in the link that you provide.

Comment: Maybe because the link was given as a caveat? Hm?

Comment: So why not change to `AC_LANG_C` where main is allowed to call main? And as said already: you are just giving some code without any explanation, but an explanation would really help.

Comment: So why not edit my answer to make it more informative instead of bickering? Goodbye.