# autoconf: best practice for including `libftdi` in `configure.ac`

Tags: c, autotools, autoconf, automake, libftdi

Hello everybody out there using GNU autoconf,

What is the best practice to look for `libftdi` and including it with `autoconf` for compiling a C program using it?
The following snippet from a `configure.ac` file works, but I'm not sure, whether it is best practice:

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([LIBFTDI], [libftdi])
#AC_CHECK_LIB([ftdi],[ftdi],[ftdi])  # Why doesn't this work?
#AC_SEARCH_LIBS([ftdi],[ftdi],[ftdi])  # Why doesn't this work?
#AC_CHECK_HEADERS([ftdi.h],[],[echo "error: missing libftdi header files" && exit 1])
LIBS="-lftdi $LIBS $LDFLAGS" # works, but is this the best way?
```

I'm building the program with `autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.69` and compiling it with `gcc version 7.5.0` on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Related: [PKG_CHECK_MODULES considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220946/pkg-check-modules-considered-harmful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why your other attempts failed

### Library tests

Your commented-out `AC_CHECK_LIB` and `AC_SEARCH_LIBS` examples do not demonstrate correct usage.  Usage details are presented [in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.63/html_node/Libraries.html#index-AC_005fCHECK_005fLIB-297), but to sum up:

- the arguments to `AC_CHECK_LIB` are

  1. The simple name of the library, *i.e.* `ftdi`
  2. **The name of a characteristic *function* provided by the library**
  3. (optional) Code for `configure` to execute in the event that the library is found.  Default is to prepend a link option to `$LIBS` and define a `HAVE_LIB*` preprocessor macro.
  4. (optional) Code for `configure` to execute in the event that the library is not found
  5. (optional) Additional library link options (not already in `$LIBS`) that are needed to link a program that uses the library being checked
- the arguments to `AC_SEARCH_LIBS` are

  1. **The name of the *function* to search for**
  2. A list of one or more library names to search
  3. (optional) Code for `configure` to execute in the event that the library is found, *in addition to* prepending a link option to `$LIBS` (but not defining any preprocessor macro)
  4. (optional) Code for `configure` to execute in the event that the library is not found
  5. (optional) Additional library link options (not already in `$LIBS` that are needed to link a program that uses the library being checked

Neither your `AC_CHECK_LIB` example nor your `AC_SEARCH_LIBS` example properly designates an existing libftdi function to check for. Moreover, the third argument in each case is unlikely to be valid shell / Autoconf code, so in the event that the library *were* found, `configure` would probably crash.  Better might be:

```
AC_CHECK_LIB([ftdi], [ftdi_init])
```

or

```
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([ftdi_init], [ftdi])
```

Depending on what exactly you want to do, on details of libftdi, and on the `configure.ac` context, you might need to provide appropriate values for some or all of the optional arguments.

The main reasons for a library check to fail despite the library in fact being installed are

- the library being installed in a location that is not in the default search path
- the library having link dependencies on other libraries, and those have not (yet) been accounted for at the time of the check

The former is analogous to header installation location considerations discussed in the next section.  The latter can be addressed by adding explicit extra link flags via the fifth argument to `AC_CHECK_LIB` or `AC_SEARCH_LIBS`, but is more often addressed semi-automatically by performing `AC_CHECK_LIB` or `AC_SEARCH_LIBS` tests in reverse prerequisite order, so that the value of `LIBS` is built up with an appropriately-ordered list of link flags, ready at each point to support the next check, and ultimately appropriate for supporting the overall compilation.

Note also that libftdi provides both C and C++ interfaces.  In `ftdi_init`, I have been careful to choose a function that has C linkage, so as to avoid C++ name-mangling issues (see [How to test a C++ library usability in configure.in?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1021962/2402272)).  You may also need to ensure that the tests are run with the C compiler (see [Language Choice](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.63/html_node/Language-Choice.html) in the Autoconf manual).

### Header test

Your `AC_CHECK_HEADERS` usage, on the other hand, does not appear to be inherently wrong.  If the resulting `configure` script does not detect `ftdi.h`, then that implies that the header isn't in the compiler's default header search path.  That might happen, for example, if it is installed in a subdirectory, such as `/usr/include/ftdi`.  This would be a matter of both ftdi and system installation convention.

**If** it is ftdi convention for the headers to be installed in a subdirectory, then your source files should specify that in their `#include` directives:

```
#include <ftdi/ftdi.h>
```

**If** your source files in fact do that, then that should also be what you tell Autoconf to look for:

```
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([ftdi/ftdi.h])
```

Regardless of whether a subdirectory prefix is expected or used, it is good practice to accommodate the possibility of headers and / or libraries being installed in a non-standard location.  Although one can always do that by specifying appropriate flags in the `CPPFLAGS` variable in `configure`'s environment, I prefer and recommend using `AC_ARG_WITH` to designate a `--with` argument or `AC_ARG_VAR` to designate an environment variable that `configure` will consult for the purpose.  For example,

```
AC_ARG_WITH([ftdi-includedir],
  [AS_HELP_STRING([--with-ftdiincludedir=dir],
    [specifies a custom directory for the libftdi header files])],
  [CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -I$withval"]
)
```

Exposing an argument or environment variable for the specific purpose highlights (in the output of `./configure --help`) the fact that this is a knob that the user might need to adjust.  Additionally, receiving the include directory via a for-purpose vector is sometimes useful for limiting in which compilations the designated include directory is made available.

## On `PKG_CHECK_MODULES`

The Autotools objective and philosophy is to support the widest possible array of build machines and environments by minimizing external dependencies and writing the most portable configuration and build code possible.  To this end, the Autotools are designed so that they themselves are not required to build projects on supported systems.  Rather, Autoconf produces `configure` as a stand-alone, highly portable shell script, and Automake produces configurable templates for highly portable makefiles.  These are intended to be included in source packages, to be used as-is on each build system.  Making your `configure` script dependent on `pkg-config` being installed on every system where your project is to be built, as using `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` does, conflicts with those objectives.

How significant an issue that may be is a subject of some dispute.  Where it is available, `pkg-config` can be very useful, especially for components that require complex build flags.  `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` is thus very convenient for both package maintainer and package builder *on those systems where it is present or readily available*, for those components that provide pkg-config metadata.

But `pkg-config` is not necessarily available for every system targeted by your software.  It cannot reasonably be assumed present or obtainable even on systems for which it is nominally available.  And even on systems that have it, pkg-config metadata for the libraries of interest are not necessarily installed with the libraries.

As such, I urge you to avoid using `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` in your Autoconf projects. You need to know how to do without it in any case, because it is not an option for some libraries.  Where appropriate, provide hooks by which the builder can supply appropriate flags, and let *them* choose whether to use `pkg-config` in conjunction with those.  Decoupling `configure` from `pkg-config` in this way makes a bit more work for you, and in some cases for builders, but it is more flexible.

### Your `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` example

Your example invocation appears ok in itself, supposing that "libftdi" is the appropriate pkg-config module name (you have to know the appropriate name):

> ```
> PKG_CHECK_MODULES([LIBFTDI], [libftdi])
> ```

But although that may yield a `configure` script that runs successfully, it does not, in itself, do much for you.  In particular, it verifies that `pkg-config` metadata for the named module is present, but

- it does not verify the presence or test the use of the library or header
- although it does set some output variables containing compile and link flags, you do not appear to be using those

  - specifically, if you're going to rely on `pkg-config`, then you should use the link flags it reports to you instead of hardcoding `-lftdi`, and that alone.

Furthermore, it is more typical to use the output variables created by `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` in your makefile than to use them to update `$LIBS` or other general variables inside `configure`.  If you do use them in `configure`, however, then it is essential to understand that `LIBS` and `LDFLAGS` have different roles with little overlap.  It is generally inappropriate, not to mention unnecessary, to include the `LDFLAGS` in `LIBS`.  If you want to update `LIBS` inside `configure`, then this would be the way to do it:

```
LIBS="$LIBFTDI_LIBS $LIBS"
```

And if you're going to do that, then you probably should do the same with the compiler flags reported by pkg-config, if any:

```
CFLAGS="$CFLAGS $LIBFTDI_CFLAGS"
```

Comment: This helped me to solve the problem. I learned a lot about autoconf from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can check it like this:

```
AC_CHECK_LIB([ftdi],[ftdi_init],[],[echo "error: missing libftdi library" && exit 1],[])
    LDFLAGS="-lftdi $LDFLAGS"
```

The second argument for AC_CHECK_LIB is a function exported by the library, and in this case the init call works well.

Answer (score 0):

If `libftdi` uses `pkg-config` (and it appears to, given you said that snippet works), the `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` is what you want. The default for `action-if-not-found` is to error out, so if this is a required dependency, it's exactly what you want.

*But* you shouldn't use `LIBS` that way. First because `LDFLAGS` does not have the same semantics as `LIBS`, second because the `pkg-config` file might have provided you with further search paths that are required.

Instead you should add to your `Makefile.am` the flags as you need them:

```
mytarget_CFLAGS = $(LIBFTDI_CFLAGS)
mytarget_LDADD = $(LIBFTDI_LIBS)
```

You can refer to my [Autotools Mythbuster — Dependency Discovery](https://autotools.io/pkgconfig/index.html) for further details on how to use `pkg-config` for dependencies. You can see there how you would generally use `AC_CHECK_LIB` or `AC_SEARCH_LIB`, but seriously if `pkg-config` works, stick to that, as it's more reliable and consistent.

Comment: I am inclined to disagree.  The problem with using `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` is that it introduces an unnecessary build-time dependency on `pkg-config`.  That the library provides `pkg-config` metadata does not imply that the `pkg-config` software will also be present.

Comment: Not my DV, by the way.

Comment: The fact that there _is_ `pkg-config` metadata, and that it works for the OP, suggests that `pkg-config` is there. The build-time dependency on it is far from unnecessary — it might be the _only_ way to correctly find the library, if it's not installed in the usual search paths.

OP is asking for *best practice*. Well, `pkg-config` is the best practice from both packagers' and maintainers' point of views.